# SCP not working in Pexpect

Tags: scp

I am trying to do SCP and copy some files from the remote server. Since i dont have root permission i use sudo with the command when it prompts for password i am sending it using pexpect but i am not able to do it. I got struck somewhere.

Here is my code:

```
import pexpect

def doScp(user,password,host,remotepath,localpath,files):
    print files

    child = pexpect.spawn('sudo scp -C %s:%s%s %s' % (host, remotepath, files, localpath))

    print 'scp -C %s:%s%s %s' % (host, remotepath, files, localpath)

    i = child.expect(['assword:', r"yes/no"], timeout=30)

    if i == 0:
        child.sendline(password)
    elif i == 1:
        child.sendline("yes")
        child.expect("assword:", timeout=30)
        child.sendline(password)
    data = child.read()
    print data
    child.close()

user = "xxxxx"

host = "yyyy"

password = "zzzzzz"
remotepath = "/opt/logs/"
localpath = "/opt/Performance_Logs/SRNG/"
files = "receiver.log"

doScp(user,password,host,remotepath,localpath,files)
```

The error I'm getting:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
    raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
child.expect("ada@ada's password:")
child.sendline("mypassword")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=10)
```

Might this link helps you :

https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/105

Comment: I am getting below error                                                                      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
    raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))